Search from SQL Database via FORM on Blazor
I am trying to search data/information in the database using Form in blazor. I tried everything from the net and I can't seem to find the right choice for it. I'm using onion structure in the blazor server.
<EditForm Enhance="true" Model="@searchQuery" OnValidSubmit="HandleSubmit" method="post" FormName="ProductPostLaunchQueryForm">

   <label for="datetime">Date & Time</label>
    <InputDate id="datetime" @bind-Value="searchQuery.DateFrom" TValue="DateOnly" min-value="2020-01-01" />


This is an example, How do I get the values from my database using this? as any of you tried Blazor there's a code block below '@code' that lets you run your c# code to access this

<label>HH</label>
<InputSelect id="hourfrom" @bind-Value="searchQuery.HourFrom">
<option value="0">--</option>
@foreach (var hour in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Hour)))
{
    string strconc = @hour.ToString();
    string mdfd = strconc.Replace('H', ' ');
    <option value="@hour">
        @mdfd.ToString()
    </option>
}
</InputSelect>


This is another example but for hour, which is in Enum. How do I get the values? I tried to store it first to an entity (model) then I will use those to search for values in the database. But it don't seem to post anything.

@code {
    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    private ProductPostLaunchQuery searchQuery { get; set; } = new();


    private async Task HandleSubmit()
    {
        await productrepository.AddAsync(searchQuery);
        Navigate.NavigateTo("/");
    }


This is my c# code, and it doesn't work

public async Task AddAsync(ProductPostLaunchQuery query)
{
    await _dbContext.ProductPostLaunchQueries.AddAsync(query);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}


This is the repository I used. Now my only problem is that it won't post to the database when I click the process button

<div id="prbtn">
    <right>
        <input type="submit" name="btnsearchnow" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnsearchnow" value="Process" />
    </right>
</div>


This is my button

I'm using Enum for InputSelect, I am using onion structure and both have IRepository, Repository, IService and Service in my folder. It just that I am really trying to figureout how can I manage to search by filling up this form. This project was tasked to localized the aspx asp.net to blazor. I really appreciate it if someone can tell me how to do that exactly, the videos on the internet are also outdated and can't be used in this scenario as they only retrieve data with all of the information in the database.

May I ask why you're (ab)using <table> for layout like it's the 1990s?

its the structure of the website that's been used, I just copied the structure of html.

So, what's the actual problem? You have a form, and you can post it somewhere? What's next?

I want to know on how to get the data that the user input and use it to search in my database.

Okej, i dunno blazor but it seems like the most basic thing in it? Did you go through the tutorials? For example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms/?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Yep I didn't go through that tutorial, I guess I'll try. Thanks

This is a wall of code with no context, that frankly I [and most others] don't have the time to wade through and figure out what you're doing.  You need to create a [MRE] that simplifies the above code into something that people without your knowledge of the application context can understand.

Noted, I'm new so I am sorry for the formatting but I edited the code. Feel free to ask if anyone need anything else.  Thanks

it won't post to the database -- Do you mean that AddAsync never runs? Or does it run and it throws an exception? BTW, don't use DbSet.AddAsync unless you really need it, use Add.

Yep it won't fetch the data from the database which is Microsoft SQl, I'm also sure I connected it because the add-migration initiate and I can see the table after updating it. And thankyou for telling me to use add. I'll try it right away
